# How to get value based on key from an array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have a state

```
    const [analysisData, setAnalysisData] = useState(false);
```

I am setting the data of this state in a function and when I console `console.log(analysisData)` I am getting the output as

```
 {ID:1, ANALYSIS_NAME : "name1",
       custodians:"[{\"ID\": 1, \"NAME\": \"abc\"}, 
                    {\"ID\": 2, \"NAME\": \"xyz\"}, 
                    {\"ID\": 3, \"NAME\": \"pqr\"}]"
    
    };
```

When I try to display in HTML as below, I am getting error

```
    const AnalysisList = () => {
    return(<div>
    <Panel>
    {JSON.parse(analysisData.custodians).map((childData) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log(childData.NAME)}
            </div>
        )}
    )}
    

    <Panel>
    </div>)
    }

    export default AnalysisList
```

I am trying to display `"Name"` inside the div in the above code.

How to display. Please help

Comment: what is error????

Comment: what is the error you are seeing ? Also your `AnalysisList` does not have the `analysisData` anywhere in its scope . Can you add the complete code of your `AnalysisList` component ? . You are setting the `analysisData` as false initially but you are getting an object in the console log . There are many missing pieces in your question . Instead of console.log inside your div you just need to do `<div{childData.NAME}</div>`

Comment: @Sowam I want "name" inside custodians

Comment: @Shyam I tried <div{childData.NAME}</div>, but I am getting the error as undefined variable

Comment: @Viet I am getting the error as undefined variable

Comment: yes because `analysisData` is not there inside your `AnalysisList` component .

Comment: are you sure that data inside custodians is in that weird format? it is a string, not an object that is why you cannot get it

Comment: @Shyam I have. Its just that I cant show all the code. I am able to see it when I console

Comment: @Sowam Yes I am sure. Its the database output. That is why I am getting like that and JSON.Parse should work. But thats not working

Answer (score 1):

Because the initial value of `analysisData` is false. So `JSON.parse(analysisData.custodians)` is return `undefined` and map will doesn't work.

You can you optional chaining to check in return:

```
{JSON.parse(analysisData.custodians)?.map((childData) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(childData.NAME)}
        </div>
    )}
)}
```